# ThreadSafety in servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, thread-safety, synchronized

There are many questions on thread safety of servlets, but I want to ask about the other classes that servlet uses.

In a normal application the servlet classes uses other normal classes also (my appl do) like in MVC. So my question is **should i declare all the functions in my model classes as synchronized**

[image]

Suppose I have 2 servlets and the use classes Dog and Cat. Both classes have some static and  non static functions and static and non static variables.

these methods uses database connection to display contents, and I got `nullpointerexception`  for this code

```
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    Statement stmt =  con.createStatement();
    select = "SELECT * FROM table";
    java.sql.ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(select);
    while(result.next())
    {
        do something
    }
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally {
    if (con != null) 
        try {
            con.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and to my surprise i get the exception in line `try { con.close(); } : nullPointerException` 
 To my understanding since I have already checked that  `if (con != null)` so `con` should 
not be null.

So,

1. Should all the functions be synchronized
2. Should all the functions using static variables be synchronized
3. Should only the static functions be synchronized  using
4. Should only the static functions using static variables be synchronized

Comment: The code you've show us is obviously "fictional", so I don't think it is fruitful to try to figure out why it doesn't "work".  But one possibility is that you are simply misinterpreting the stacktrace.

Comment: In your real code, is "con" a static variable ?

Comment: yes I was using con as static by mistake, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a servlet, it is generally poor design ... and possibly a mistake ... to have static variables.  But if you do use (and need to use) static variables, then the code that accesses and updates them would need to be properly synchronized.  (Servlet code is executed on multiple threads ... unless you hobble the web container framework by configuring only one worker thread.)

Declaring the methods as `synchronized` is one way to achieve this, if you do it properly.

However ...

Simply declaring methods to be `synchronized` willy-nilly is a bad idea.  You need to understand the anticipated concurrency patterns of your code before you start adding the synchronization.  Mindless addition of `synchronized` can lead to concurrency bottlenecks, and potential deadlocks.  (And you can still have thread-safety issues ... if the granularity of mutual exclusion is not right for the problem.)

---

I concur with @Roman C's Answer.  You should NOT be attempting to share the same database connection across multiple requests ... if that is what you are actually doing.  I suggest you look into use a database connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use static in the other classes. Then you shouldn't scary about threadsafety, JDBC API take care about it. But if you share some objects between servlets, say in the some context, then you should synchronize the container which gets access to it. This is a reason to use some frameworks based on servlet technology that are created to help you better use your other objects and use them in thread safe manner. Raw servlets are powerful but you have to solve problems you encounter yourself further trying to reinvent the wheel.

About exception catching, it could thrown in the first statement, so the `con` object remains not initialized. Manually managing connections (if any) is not a good way because you stuck with the same problem to synchronize them. As a standard of JDBC provide you API for managing connections via pooling, so you don't have ro reinvent the wheel providing your own synchronization methods.